# Evaluate String expression in Swift just like javascript eval

Tags: swift, string, expression, evaluate

I am getting dynamic conditions through API to apply in the application. It could be any logical expression. The task is to run all the condition received in mobile app and proceed further as per the result of evaluation.

Example :

```
"conditionInfos": [
    {
      "errorMessage": "Error message",
      "condition": "@City == \"xyz\" AND @Hobby == "\"gardening\""
    },
    {
      "errorMessage": "error",
      "condition": "@CountryCode == +91 OR @CountryCode == +1",
    }
```

I am replacing value of entities (prefixed with @) with the actual values & the logical separator if any like AND and OR with respective (&&, ||) symbols.

The string expression then created needs to be evaluate.

I checked NSExpression in swift but that works only for Mathematical expressions and is throwing error in my case.

I saw same had been done through **eval** in javascript and I need same for Swift language.

Kindly guide.

Comment: Sorry but what is the end goal here, you say it needs to evaluate and retrieve the result but what result is that and retrieve how?

Comment: And what do you want to filter? You might construct a `NSPredicate` with that, but that's a little risky though.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: The goal is to evaluate the conditions received through api after putting all relevant data. I need to perform action on the basis of its success or failure. As given in dummy example if input city is xyz and input hobby is gardening then perform certain action else reject the input. Let me know if need more clarification

Comment: I still don’t understand what you are asking about and what kind of answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptCore Framework bundled with Xcode seems helpful to evaluate JS code. The below code runs in the playground.

```swift
import JavaScriptCore
let context:JSContext = JSContext()

context.evaluateScript("var factorial = function(n) { if(n<0){return;}if(n===0){return 1;}return n*factorial(n-1); }")

let result: JSValue = context.evaluateScript("factorial(3)")

print(result.toInt32()) // => 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't need JS code I need native iOS swift code